# Reloading is not consistent in different browsers

Tags: java, gwt, browser, jsni

We are working with the gwt-java application. In one case i need to reload my browser window in my application, that's why i wanted to use 'Window.Location.reload()' which is not working consistently
then i used force reloading of an application which is working in 'Chrome' but continuously reloading window in Firefox and IE(not working properly).

Chrome - Version 40.0.2214.45 beta-m (64-bit)
Firefox - 24.0
IE - 11

### forceReload():

```
 private static native void forceReload() /*-{
  $wnd.location.reload(true);
}-*/;
```

what is the best way to reload browser window?

Comment: Please paint a wider picture of your issue, e.g. your code that (conditionally?) invokes the `forceReload`.

Answer (score 0):

two options:

1) `Window.Location.reload()`;

Reloads the current browser window. All `GWT` state will be lost.

2) `Window.Location.replace("myUrl")`;

Replaces the current URL with a new one. All `GWT` state will be lost. In the browser's history, the current URL will be replaced by the new URL.

also, `window.location.reload(true)`
refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Methods)

Something as below

```
public static native void reload(boolean force) /*-{
  $wnd.location.reload(force);
}-*/;   // by default force reload is false
```

Comment: Thank you @ankur, but i am getting problems with different browsers.

Comment: @User please post for which browsers it works fine, and for which does not, plus check for browser and OS compatibility as well if required in your case.

Comment: @User have you tried using `Window.Location.replace("myUrl")`

Comment: I can try that with url but i need to construct url for that.

Comment: @User i hope you get the current window url `Window.Location.getHref()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68468/discussion-between-user-and-ankur-singhal).

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you only want your page to reload one time when the condition meet? I edited my answer, and see whether you can add a "dummy flag" to indicate the event/ condition to load it for one time only.

```
if (YourCondition == true && yourConditionFlag  == true){

    yourConditionFlag = false;
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: yes exactly, but the loading is happening forever even if i have condition like above in firefox and ie.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned what is the condition are? some code maybe, see whether the edited answer fix your need?

Comment: it is our own condition like: if(existingId.equals(newId) == false) { private static native void forceReload() /*-{
  $wnd.location.reload(true);
}-*/; }

Comment: This will very likely not help since after reload all GWT (client side) state is lost. `yourConditionFlag` doesn't survive the reload.

Comment: If you can pass the `yourConditionFlag` value to servlet? [Please refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472199/access-gwt-post-parameters-via-servlet)